# Swift Table View Controller Segue Not Working Automatically

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

Steps taken:

1. Created new single view project
2. Deleted default view controller
3. Added new Table View Controller
4. Embedded TVC into a Navigation Controller
5. Added a child TVC
6. Added custom class files and associated to each TVC
7. Created a Show segue from the first TVC to the child
8. Implemented required methods, #of sections, # of rows, cellForRowAtIndexPath

All of the tutorials I have watched and read online only include the steps I show above, and the segues start working fine.  However, in my case I can not get it to work until I add the following:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("detail", sender: tableView)
}
```

I'm totally fine with implementing the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method if it is required.  I'm just wondering if I am missing something, because it seems to work automatically in everything I've seen online.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To get it to work without having to implement the delegate method you have to drag the `segue` from the cell to the `Detail View Controller` you are most likely dragging the `segue` from the `controller` to the `detail`

Comment: I made sure I dragged from the cell to the controller.  I wish it was that simple.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your contributions.  I figured out that the problem was the following was missing from the cellForRowAtIndexPath tableView function.

```
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("custom", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
```

I had this line commented out, mostly because I have no idea what it does.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the segue (storyboard) and on the side menu you have to assign the text "detail" from

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("detail", sender: tableView)
```

on the **Identifier** field.

Like the image below

[image]

**Edit:**

Try the code above, rembember to change NAME_OF_THE_DETAIL_VIEW_CONTROLLER to your Detail ViewController.

In this code we set i set "*self*" before the *performSegueWithIdentifier*. And when the button is clicked you set the *segue.destinationViewController* to your new ViewController.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detail", sender: indexPath);
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "detail") {
        var detailView =  segue.destinationViewController as! NAME_OF_THE_DETAIL_VIEW_CONTROLLER 
    }
}
```

Comment: Did that...  remember, this all works if I add the didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @GED125  i've edited my answer with a new possible solution. Try use this.